# For R function: How to show the list of toss times which roll in number"n" for n-face dice when taking X attempts with a while loop?

Tags: r, statistics

**For R function:**

i.e: for repeating tossing the 6-side dice scenario for 3 attempts,  1st attempts toss 3 times to get "6", 2nd attempts toss 1 time and 3rd toss 4 times, so return [3,1,4]

```
roll <- function(n, X){
  a <- 0
  y <- sample(1:n, size=X, replace=TRUE)
  while (y!=n){
    a <- a+1
    return(a)
    }
} 

roll(6,5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by [@James Curran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61551465/12158757), the easiest way is applying the negative binomial distribution.

If you would like to define your custom function `roll`, you can try the code below

```
roll <- function(n, X){
  res <- rep(0,X)
  for (i in 1:X) {
    a <- 0
    repeat {
      if (sample(n,1)==n) break
      a <- a + 1
    }
    res[i] <- a + 1
  }
  res
}
```

or

```
roll <- function(n, X){
  res <- rep(0,X)
  for (i in 1:X) {
    a <- 0
    while (sample(n,1)!=n) {
      a <- a + 1
    }
    res[i] <- a + 1
  }
  res
}
```

Comment: thank you, but if I really want to use the while loop, what should I do?

Comment: @AlthorpFalnders Yes. You can try that and will see

Comment: one more question: why there are 0 sometimes? should I set a <- 1?

Comment: @AlthorpFalnders 0 means you had zero failure, so your total number of roll is 1. You can initialize a by 1, then you can use res[i] <- a instead

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the negative binomial distribution. The negative binomial distribution models the probability that you have n "failures" before "r" successes. So

```
> set.set(100)
> rnbinom(3,  size = 1, prob = 1/6)
[1] 3 7 0
```

does your three experiments. The first took 3 throws to get a 6, the second 7, and the third rolled a 6 on the first throw.

Comment: Voted for your smart `rnbinom` approach! I guess it should be `rnbinom(3,  size = 1, prob = 1/6)+1`, where the last success should be taken into account for the total number of rolls